# Unresponsive mouse and keyboard on login screen (macbook pro 2015)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login-screen, osx-el-capitan, unresponsive

When I boot the laptop from shutdown state (not resuming or awakening), it quickly goes to the login screen as normal but the mouse and keyboard seem unresponsive, but not completely:

Every like 5-7 seconds I'm able to enter a keystroke or move the mouse. Using those time windows I'm able to enter the password and successful login.

Once I login, the laptop works perfectly fine and stable.

This is the log I recorded today when it happened again: 
http://pastebin.com/zaDp9xg9

It happens every time I fully reboot or shutdown the laptop, don't have any problems with suspension and awakening.

If I reboot resetting the PRAM, the problem doesn't appear until the next shutdown reboot. So what I usually do is reset the PRAM every time I boot.

I reinstalled the OS from scratch and the issue is still there. I also use FileVault.

Have anybody experienced a similar issue? Do you see anything strange in the log?

Thanks

Comment: I experience the same problems on a Macbook Pro Retina 13" 2016, fully updated. Did you make any progress? I noticed that if you force restart (by pressing and holding the power button) at the unresponsive login screen then at the next boot mouse and keyboard work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took the laptop the the official service and it was a faulty I/O board. They changed it and now it's working fine. Notice that I didn't get a full motherboard replace, just something called "I/O Board".

Answer (score 2):

I was just having problems with logging into my MacBook Pro, the cursor was moving but the password field wasn’t showing and I couldn’t seem to select anything on the screen. The tab key didn’t work, but the arrow keys did! I just hit the down arrow and the password field appeared enabling me to enter my password....phew! Thought I would share in case it helps others....

Comment: Surprisingly, this also worked for me, although it wasn't completely clear that the arrows alone did it. Using Command+arrow and arrow alone didn't do much.  Then I pressed the "Play" key, and the Mac started playing back my voice memos.  I clicked the popup with the mouse, then was able to go back and click the login popup.  Long story short, thanks for giving me hope!

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue happening right now. Thanks for the resetting PRAM suggestion! I would add the following as a comment, but not enough reputation yet.

If anyone else runs into this, here are the instructions for resetting PRAM - https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-reset-mac-pram-or-nvram-2260839.

On pre-late 2016 Macbook Pros:

1. Shutdown the computer
2. Turn the computer back on
3. Immediately press and hold the following keys: cmd+option+P+R
4. Continue holding those keys until you hear the second startup chime and then release the keys
5. Computer should startup normally

On late 2016 Macbook Pros and later:

1. Shutdown the computer
2. Turn the computer back on
3. Immediately press and hold the following keys: cmd+option+P+R for a minimum of 20 seconds (longer is fine)
4. After 20 second release the keys and computer should start up normally

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with macbook pro 2017 (touch bar). keyboard not working after restart and I'm stuck in login screen. I just noticed that it's related to an accesibility option "slow key", try type and hold the keys while typing like a long press.!!
Then it works!

Comment: But it was faulty I/O problem

Answer (score 0):

I found that unplugging the keyboard from the USB port, and plugging it into a different USB port seemed to fix the issue for me!